# How Apple localize iOs users?

Tags: ios, localization, in-app

How does Apple define an iOs user localization ?

I am using IP to restict in-app view for non-available in-apps in some territories, but Apple tells me those in-apps are still sold in forbidden countries (in the monthly report).

I guess Apple is using the user store / declared country or something specific to the user, making a difference in their transactions localization en mine.

Comment: you have a language setting of your iOS device which you can set to whatever you want and you can create multiple Apple accounts for different countries and on top of that you can physically be wherever you want to be - I have one german and one american account for example while my phone language is english and I am in germany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those In-App purchases Apple tells you refer to user's store account, not language, nor geolocation or IP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Apple is using the users stores to geolocalize them.